# How do i stop my player falling through the floor? and play the audio when it lands on it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The way I want my audio to work is that when my player hits the ground object it plays the hit sound but when I set me ground object to is trigger. My player just falls trough the ground. And I have tried following tutorials on this.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Audio;

    public class PlaySound : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public AudioSource HitsGround;

        void OnTriggerEnter()
        {
           HitsGround.Play();
        }
```

Comment: in this case the code you posted is likely not the problem. when the ground collision detection stops working on attaching the sound trigger, we need to see that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely that you have the ground collider set to be a trigger, trigger colliders in unity are not solid and can be passed through.

You'll want to make sure the collider on your ground is not set to be a trigger:

[image: trigger]

One solution would be to add a second collider to your ground object that *is* set to be a trigger and use this to play your sound.

Comment: Thanks you so much Jake. I have been trying to accomplish this for weeks now :)